# how to disable previous dates in calender in php?

Tags: javascript

```
  $('#eventDate-container .input-group.date').datepicker({
    weekStart: 1, // calendar starts on Monday
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    startDate: "4/10/2017", // disables all dates prior to this date
    datesDisabled: ['01/01/1970', '12/31/2099'] // placeholder sample for possible future use
  });
```

Comment: Please add more.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone if they're wanting to do this in php, then the tag should have probably been kept.

Answer (score 0):

first i think that what you need is a "**jquery**" code not in "**PHP**"
, you can disable previous dates from **jquery datepicker** by using `minDate:` option

**like** :

```
var tardate = new Date("4/10/2017");
    $("#eventDate-container").datepicker({
        weekStart: 1, // calendar starts on Monday
            autoclose: true,
            todayHighlight: true,
            minDate: tardate,
    });
```

here's **jsfiddle** [link](https://jsfiddle.net/vztf5r16/2/)